# Ubuntu 16.04: Executable added in .desktop opens without the file

Tags: command-line, unity

I added Pymol executable into `~/.local/share/applications` as a pymol.desktop file. The program now shows up in the Applications tab of the GUI and opens but without the file.

I mean to say, Pymol launches without opening the PDB file.

Below is the content of the pymol.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Pymol
Type=Application
Comment=Pymol
Encoding=UTF-8
GenericName = Molecular visualisation
MimeType=chemical/x-mmcif;chemical/x-mol2;chemical/x-pdb;chemical/x-spdbv;
Exec=/opt/pymol-svn/pymol -- %f
```

How can I make Pymol launch and open the PDB file?